# Resize /boot partition on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, partition

I keep getting low disc space on /boot. It is less than 500 Mb in size. Is there a way I can resize and expand it? I have over 200 Gb free on root.

Comment: 1. Do you have any unallocated drive space? 2. What filesystem are you using on root?

Comment: 3. Do you have old kernels laying around in `/boot` that you're not using any longer?  You can remove old kernel packages to clean those up.

Comment: /boot/efi : 512 MB : fat32, 

/boot : 488 MB : ext2, 

mint-vg : 237.50 GB : lvm2 pv

Comment: I removed the kernels, but is there a way to still extend the partition?

Comment: You can do it, but you will definitely need to backup your data as it can be potentially destructive.  The main problem is that you need to shrink a PV which has one or more LVs inside of it - furthermore, you're moving the front of the partition over to extend the back of the previous.  It *can* be done, its just rather involved compared to other partition resizes.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/252204/how-to-shrink-ubuntu-lvm-logical-and-physical-volumes shows an example

Comment: I dont understand  the problem. On our servers (centos, debian and ubuntu)  we have a tiny /boot, with about 30 Mbytes free : they are running smooth from years.

Comment: I am fairly new to Linux and didn't know that downloaded and inactive Kernels stay inside /boot and hog memory. I will clean them up on regular basis from now on.

Answer (score 1):

After removing old kernels, you need to do some purging to get it all nice and clean.

This will show you, which kernel packages have been removed:

```
dpkg --list | grep "^rc  linux-image" | cut -d " " -f 3
```

Now you purge them one by one with:

```
sudo apt-get purge PACKAGE
```

That's all related to kernels in Linux Mint. After-removal procedure you might call it.

Comment: Woah woah woah, don't just go purging kernels directly, you should be using `sudo apt autoremove --purge` instead of playing whack-a-mole with old kernels... also this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Schives Because in Linux Mint your command does do anything with old removed kernels.

Comment: You shouldn't have anything to purge if you used `--purge` option with autoremove in the first place...

Comment: @Schives You obviously don't know what you are talking about. So, I unfollow your commentary.